# Multiple School Management System with Firebase

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have an idea to develop a multiple school management system web app using **Google firebase,** but I don't know how go about it yet because am still a young programmer. please can anyone help with  the followings.

1. How the data base will look like in **firestore.**(In such a way that it
   will accommodate multiple schools, staffs and student.)
2. The **security Rule** to deny and allow access to Collections and Documents

Please also suggest a better and easy way this project can be achieve. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Make the security only private read and write in the firebase CLOUD database, so that only you can write or read to the database. Make sure that the firestore structure has a collection of "schools" where you can put separate schools in the collection with the fields of name, location, and other information about the school. The ID is automatically provided. You should be able to work something out of that from there. Please mark this as the answer if this was helpful by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to know more about the staffs, students, grades and attendance Collections and Documents

Comment: all of those can be different collections under the schools collection, where it could have sub parameters and collections.